# Attribute Error: object has no attribute in python

Tags: python, object, attributes

I have the following class Ui_MainWindow(object). However I get the Attribute Error, that `AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'ser'` 
.ser is before defindet in the check_phone() method. The problem occurs in the sendMessage() method.
How comes that .ser is not recognized anymore?

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkFileDialog as filedialog
    import tkMessageBox
    import serial
    import time

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(503, 486)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.send_sms) #send sms function

    def check_phone(self):
         ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 
                 460800, 
                 timeout=5, 
                 xonxoff = False,   
                 rtscts = False, 
                 bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, 
                 parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, 
                 stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

    def sendMessage(self):
        self.ser.write('ATZ\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write('AT+CMGF=1\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write('''AT+CMGS="''' + self.recipient + '''"\r''')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write(self.content + "\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write(chr(26))
        time.sleep(2)

    def send_sms(self):
    check = self.radioButton.isChecked() #stuff doesnt work yet!
    test =  self.lineEdit.text()
    print(test)
    if check == True:
        if not self.lineEdit.text():
            root = tk.Tk()
            root.withdraw()
            tkMessageBox.showwarning("Phone Number Missing!", "Please enter a valid phone number")
            root.destroy()
            root.mainloop()
            return
        if not self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText():
            root = tk.Tk()
            root.withdraw()
            tkMessageBox.showwarning("Message Missing!", "Please enter a text message")
            root.destroy()
            root.mainloop()
            return
        else:
            sms = Ui_MainWindow(self.lineEdit.text(), self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText())
            sms.check_phone()
            sms.sendMessage()
            sms.disconnectPhone()
            self.plainTextEdit2.setText('message sent successfully')
```

Comment: Your indentation is off, but it's pretty clear that you don't actually assign to **`self.`** `ser` in the `check_phone` method. It's just a local variable that's dereferenced as soon as the method call ends.

Answer (score 6):

As Jon points out, you're assigning `serial.Serial` to a (soon-discarded) local variable in `check_phone` rather than to an instance attribute.

Replace this:

```
def check_phone(self):
     ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 
             460800, 
             timeout=5, 
             xonxoff = False,   
             rtscts = False, 
             bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, 
             parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, 
             stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
```

With this:

```
def check_phone(self):
     self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 
             460800, 
             timeout=5, 
             xonxoff = False,   
             rtscts = False, 
             bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, 
             parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, 
             stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact that was the problem. In fact ser was just local! I have not seen this at all.

Comment: @fahrradlaus - accept this answer so we know its right at a glace.... and Tagc gets 15 shiny points to boot!